# How to fix "Unknown error" error in Xdebug PHP

Tags: php, sublimetext3, xdebug

I'm trying to debug some code for a project I'm working on (Laravel), I have installed Xdebug on my webserver (XAMPP), installed the web plugin for Chrome but for some reason Xdebug is giving me an Unknown error message on the logs and the breakpoint isn't met.

I'm using Sublime text with the proper package of Xdebug to work with.

This is the log its giving me when trying to debug

```
[14740] Log opened at 2019-08-17 04:18:55
[14740] I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
[14740] I: Connected to client. :-)
[14740] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/LivingWriter/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.3.6-dev" protocol_version="1.0" appid="14740" idekey="Henoc"><engine version="2.7.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2019 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
[14740]
[14740] <- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>
[14740]
[14740] <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_children -v 32
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>
[14740]
[14740] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_data -v 1024
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_data" success="1"></response>
[14740]
[14740] <- feature_set -i 4 -n max_depth -v 1
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>
[14740]
[14740] <- breakpoint_set -i 5 -f file%3A//C%3A%5Cxampp%5Chtdocs%5CLivingWriter%5Croutes%5Cweb.php -n 21 -t line
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="5" id="147400001"></response>
[14740]
[14740] <- breakpoint_set -i 6 -t exception -x "Fatal error"
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6" id="147400002"></response>
[14740]
[14740] <- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t exception -x "Catchable fatal error"
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" id="147400003"></response>
[14740]
[14740] <- breakpoint_set -i 8 -t exception -x "Warning"
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="8" id="147400004"></response>
[14740]
[14740] <- breakpoint_set -i 9 -t exception -x "Parse error"
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="9" id="147400005"></response>
[14740]
[14740] <- breakpoint_set -i 10 -t exception -x "Notice"
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="10" id="147400006"></response>
[14740]
[14740] <- breakpoint_set -i 11 -t exception -x "Strict standards"
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="11" id="147400007"></response>
[14740]
[14740] <- breakpoint_set -i 12 -t exception -x "Deprecated"
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="12" id="147400008"></response>
[14740]
[14740] <- breakpoint_set -i 13 -t exception -x "Xdebug"
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="13" id="147400009"></response>
[14740]
[14740] <- breakpoint_set -i 14 -t exception -x "Unknown error"
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="14" id="147400010"></response>
[14740]
[14740] <- run -i 15
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="15" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/LivingWriter/routes/web.php" lineno="21"></xdebug:message></response>
[14740]
[14740] <- context_get -i 16 -c 1
[14740] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="16" context="1"><property name="$_COOKIE" fullname="$_COOKIE" type="array" children="1" numchildren="6" page="0" pagesize="32"><property name="_ga" fullname="$_COOKIE[&quot;_ga&quot;]" type="string" size="26" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[R0ExLjEuNDQxNjA0MDExLjE1NjU1NjY3Njk=]]></property><property name="_gid" fullname="$_COOKIE[&quot;_gid&quot;]" type="string" size="27" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[R0ExLjEuMTg3NTQ5NzI1MS4xNTY1NTY2NzY5]]></property><property name="storylist" fullname="$_COOKIE[&quot;storylist&quot;]" type="string" size="6" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[bm9ybWFs]]></property><property name="XSRF-TOKEN" fullname="$_COOKIE[&quot;XSRF-TOKEN&quot;]" type="string" size="244" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ZXlKcGRpSTZJbWcxUW10TU5FdFdaMnBTT0d0VFlqbDFaR3MwZW5jOVBTSXNJblpoYkhWbElqb2lSR294YkZsSk4yeGplbVZoTnpsNlNqUkpkRmRaTjJWeGMxcFVWbTVHUkdkSVlrUlZWbFpEV25wT2VUbFRkVVprV1ZGaEsweEpVak4wU1hwcE9HazFkU0lzSW0xaFl5STZJamxsTm1Rek5EVXhPRE0yWlRsaE1ERmpObU5pWm1KbU1UUXpOalpqTlRnMFpXWTJZamd6Wm1NMU0yTmtOekF6TlRFNU9UWmxNakZoWVRrNU5UVXhOeklpZlE9PQ==]]></property><property name="livingwriter_session" fullname="$_COOKIE[&quot;livingwriter_session&quot;]" type="string" size="244" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ZXlKcGRpSTZJbGhhWEM5MEswZ3dhMGhxUmpCVlJsUk5kbVUxVW5WQlBUMGlMQ0oyWVd4MVpTSTZJbFV6YjNsSWVsQXhWMGhWVlVWc1dsQTNNbWx2TlhkR1MyTjVOazVxZFN0S2NWTklTMjVDY0V4c01VOURTMUpNUnpCWVNtOUJRMDVCV0dSTFhDOVpiems1SWl3aWJXRmpJam9pT0RRME9HSmxZMlZrTlRZek9HSXpPVEEzTXpkbU0yWmhZV05sWVdaaE1EVmpOelUwTW1SbE5EVm1aVEEyTURoa01XWXpNamhrWldSa016RmpNVEUwTVNKOQ==]]></property><property name="XDEBUG_SESSION" fullname="$_COOKIE[&quot;XDEBUG_SESSION&quot;]" type="string" size="14" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[WERFQlVHX0VDTElQU0U=]]></property></property><property name="$_ENV" fullname="$_ENV" type="array" children="1" numchildren="45" page="0" pagesize="32"><property name="ASSET_URL" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;ASSET_URL&quot;]" type="string" size="29" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9MaXZpbmdXcml0ZXI=]]></property><property name="FORCE_HTTPS" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;FORCE_HTTPS&quot;]" type="string" size="5" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ZmFsc2U=]]></property><property name="APP_NAME" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;APP_NAME&quot;]" type="string" size="12" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[TGl2aW5nV3JpdGVy]]></property><property name="APP_ENV" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;APP_ENV&quot;]" type="string" size="5" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[bG9jYWw=]]></property><property name="APP_KEY" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;APP_KEY&quot;]" type="string" size="51" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[YmFzZTY0OjltcUtmY0grcCtvdGN5WVRydjFKSG5iOUJBNEhJM3pXSi9WVVIrekdhZTA9]]></property><property name="APP_DEBUG" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;APP_DEBUG&quot;]" type="string" size="4" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[dHJ1ZQ==]]></property><property name="APP_URL" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;APP_URL&quot;]" type="string" size="29" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9MaXZpbmdXcml0ZXI=]]></property><property name="LOG_CHANNEL" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;LOG_CHANNEL&quot;]" type="string" size="5" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[c3RhY2s=]]></property><property name="DB_CONNECTION" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;DB_CONNECTION&quot;]" type="string" size="5" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[bXlzcWw=]]></property><property name="DB_HOST" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;DB_HOST&quot;]" type="string" size="9" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[bG9jYWxob3N0]]></property><property name="DB_PORT" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;DB_PORT&quot;]" type="string" size="4" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MzMwNg==]]></property><property name="DB_DATABASE" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;DB_DATABASE&quot;]" type="string" size="21" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[bGl2aW5nd3JfbGl2aW5nd3JpdGVy]]></property><property name="DB_USERNAME" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;DB_USERNAME&quot;]" type="string" size="4" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[cm9vdA==]]></property><property name="DB_PASSWORD" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;DB_PASSWORD&quot;]" type="string" size="0" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[]]></property><property name="BROADCAST_DRIVER" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;BROADCAST_DRIVER&quot;]" type="string" size="3" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[bG9n]]></property><property name="CACHE_DRIVER" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;CACHE_DRIVER&quot;]" type="string" size="4" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ZmlsZQ==]]></property><property name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;QUEUE_CONNECTION&quot;]" type="string" size="4" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[c3luYw==]]></property><property name="SESSION_DRIVER" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;SESSION_DRIVER&quot;]" type="string" size="4" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ZmlsZQ==]]></property><property name="SESSION_LIFETIME" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;SESSION_LIFETIME&quot;]" type="string" size="3" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MTIw]]></property><property name="REDIS_HOST" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;REDIS_HOST&quot;]" type="string" size="9" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MTI3LjAuMC4x]]></property><property name="REDIS_PASSWORD" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;REDIS_PASSWORD&quot;]" type="string" size="4" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[bnVsbA==]]></property><property name="REDIS_PORT" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;REDIS_PORT&quot;]" type="string" size="4" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[NjM3OQ==]]></property><property name="MAIL_DRIVER" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;MAIL_DRIVER&quot;]" type="string" size="8" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[c2VuZG1haWw=]]></property><property name="MAIL_HOST" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;MAIL_HOST&quot;]" type="string" size="14" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[c210cC5nbWFpbC5jb20=]]></property><property name="MAIL_PORT" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;MAIL_PORT&quot;]" type="string" size="3" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[NDY1]]></property><property name="MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS&quot;]" type="string" size="29" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[TGl2aW5nV3JpdGVyQGxpdmluZ3dyaXRlci5jb20=]]></property><property name="MAIL_FROM_NAME" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;MAIL_FROM_NAME&quot;]" type="string" size="12" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[TGl2aW5nV3JpdGVy]]></property><property name="MAIL_USERNAME" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;MAIL_USERNAME&quot;]" type="string" size="22" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[aGVsbG9AbGl2aW5nd3JpdGVyLmNvbQ==]]></property><property name="MAIL_PASSWORD" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;MAIL_PASSWORD&quot;]" type="string" size="16" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[TGl2aW5nV3JpdGVyMzI4IQ==]]></property><property name="MAIL_ENCRYPTION" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;MAIL_ENCRYPTION&quot;]" type="string" size="3" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[dGxz]]></property><property name="PUSHER_APP_ID" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;PUSHER_APP_ID&quot;]" type="string" size="0" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[]]></property><property name="PUSHER_APP_KEY" fullname="$_ENV[&quot;PUSHER_APP_KEY&quot;]" type="string" size="0" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[]]></property></property><property name="$_FILES" fullname="$_FILES" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="32"></property><property name="$_GET" fullname="$_GET" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="32"></property><property name="$_POST" fullname="$_POST" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="32"></property><property name="$_REQUEST" fullname="$_REQUEST" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="32"></property><property name="$_SERVER" fullname="$_SERVER" type="array" children="1" numchildren="89" page="0" pagesize="32"><property name="MIBDIRS" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;MIBDIRS&quot;]" type="string" size="24" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[QzoveGFtcHAvcGhwL2V4dHJhcy9taWJz]]></property><property name="MYSQL_HOME" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;MYSQL_HOME&quot;]" type="string" size="16" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[XHhhbXBwXG15c3FsXGJpbg==]]></property><property name="OPENSSL_CONF" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;OPENSSL_CONF&quot;]" type="string" size="31" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[QzoveGFtcHAvYXBhY2hlL2Jpbi9vcGVuc3NsLmNuZg==]]></property><property name="PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR&quot;]" type="string" size="10" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[XHhhbXBwXHBocA==]]></property><property name="PHPRC" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;PHPRC&quot;]" type="string" size="10" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[XHhhbXBwXHBocA==]]></property><property name="TMP" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;TMP&quot;]" type="string" size="10" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[XHhhbXBwXHRtcA==]]></property><property name="HTTP_HOST" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;HTTP_HOST&quot;]" type="string" size="9" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[bG9jYWxob3N0]]></property><property name="HTTP_CONNECTION" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;HTTP_CONNECTION&quot;]" type="string" size="10" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[a2VlcC1hbGl2ZQ==]]></property><property name="HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS&quot;]" type="string" size="1" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MQ==]]></property><property name="HTTP_USER_AGENT" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;HTTP_USER_AGENT&quot;]" type="string" size="115" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFdpbmRvd3MgTlQgMTAuMDsgV2luNjQ7IHg2NCkgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM3LjM2IChLSFRNTCwgbGlrZSBHZWNrbykgQ2hyb21lLzc2LjAuMzgwOS4xMDAgU2FmYXJpLzUzNy4zNg==]]></property><property name="HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE&quot;]" type="string" size="8" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[bmF2aWdhdGU=]]></property><property name="HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER&quot;]" type="string" size="2" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[PzE=]]></property><property name="HTTP_ACCEPT" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;HTTP_ACCEPT&quot;]" type="string" size="118" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[dGV4dC9odG1sLGFwcGxpY2F0aW9uL3hodG1sK3htbCxhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi94bWw7cT0wLjksaW1hZ2Uvd2VicCxpbWFnZS9hcG5nLCovKjtxPTAuOCxhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi9zaWduZWQtZXhjaGFuZ2U7dj1iMw==]]></property><property name="HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE&quot;]" type="string" size="4" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[bm9uZQ==]]></property><property name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING&quot;]" type="string" size="17" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[Z3ppcCwgZGVmbGF0ZSwgYnI=]]></property><property name="HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE&quot;]" type="string" size="36" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ZW4tVVMsZW47cT0wLjksZXMtNDE5O3E9MC44LGVzO3E9MC43]]></property><property name="HTTP_COOKIE" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;HTTP_COOKIE&quot;]" type="string" size="641" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[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]]></property><property name="PATH" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;PATH&quot;]" type="string" size="579" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[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]]></property><property name="SystemRoot" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;SystemRoot&quot;]" type="string" size="10" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[QzpcV2luZG93cw==]]></property><property name="COMSPEC" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;COMSPEC&quot;]" type="string" size="27" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[QzpcV2luZG93c1xzeXN0ZW0zMlxjbWQuZXhl]]></property><property name="PATHEXT" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;PATHEXT&quot;]" type="string" size="53" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[LkNPTTsuRVhFOy5CQVQ7LkNNRDsuVkJTOy5WQkU7LkpTOy5KU0U7LldTRjsuV1NIOy5NU0M=]]></property><property name="WINDIR" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;WINDIR&quot;]" type="string" size="10" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[QzpcV2luZG93cw==]]></property><property name="SERVER_SIGNATURE" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;SERVER_SIGNATURE&quot;]" type="string" size="94" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[PGFkZHJlc3M+QXBhY2hlLzIuNC4zNyAoV2luMzIpIE9wZW5TU0wvMS4xLjFhIFBIUC83LjMuMSBTZXJ2ZXIgYXQgbG9jYWxob3N0IFBvcnQgODA8L2FkZHJlc3M+Cg==]]></property><property name="SERVER_SOFTWARE" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;SERVER_SOFTWARE&quot;]" type="string" size="46" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[QXBhY2hlLzIuNC4zNyAoV2luMzIpIE9wZW5TU0wvMS4xLjFhIFBIUC83LjMuMQ==]]></property><property name="SERVER_NAME" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;SERVER_NAME&quot;]" type="string" size="9" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[bG9jYWxob3N0]]></property><property name="SERVER_ADDR" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;SERVER_ADDR&quot;]" type="string" size="3" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[Ojox]]></property><property name="SERVER_PORT" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;SERVER_PORT&quot;]" type="string" size="2" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ODA=]]></property><property name="REMOTE_ADDR" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;REMOTE_ADDR&quot;]" type="string" size="3" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[Ojox]]></property><property name="DOCUMENT_ROOT" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;DOCUMENT_ROOT&quot;]" type="string" size="15" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[QzoveGFtcHAvaHRkb2Nz]]></property><property name="REQUEST_SCHEME" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;REQUEST_SCHEME&quot;]" type="string" size="4" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[aHR0cA==]]></property><property name="CONTEXT_PREFIX" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;CONTEXT_PREFIX&quot;]" type="string" size="0" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[]]></property><property name="CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT" fullname="$_SERVER[&quot;CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT&quot;]" type="string" size="15" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[QzoveGFtcHAvaHRkb2Nz]]></property></property><property name="$GLOBALS" fullname="$GLOBALS" type="array" children="1" numchildren="14" page="0" pagesize="32"><property name="_GET" fullname="$GLOBALS[&quot;_GET&quot;]" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0"></property><property name="_POST" fullname="$GLOBALS[&quot;_POST&quot;]" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0"></property><property name="_COOKIE" fullname="$GLOBALS[&quot;_COOKIE&quot;]" type="array" children="1" numchildren="6"></property><property name="_FILES" fullname="$GLOBALS[&quot;_FILES&quot;]" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0"></property><property name="_ENV" fullname="$GLOBALS[&quot;_ENV&quot;]" type="array" children="1" numchildren="45"></property><property name="_REQUEST" fullname="$GLOBALS[&quot;_REQUEST&quot;]" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0"></property><property name="_SERVER" fullname="$GLOBALS[&quot;_SERVER&quot;]" type="array" children="1" numchildren="89"></property><property name="uri" fullname="$GLOBALS[&quot;uri&quot;]" type="string" size="14" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L0xpdmluZ1dyaXRlci8=]]></property><property name="app" fullname="$GLOBALS[&quot;app&quot;]" type="object" classname="Illuminate\Foundation\Application" children="1" numchildren="32"></property><property name="kernel" fullname="$GLOBALS[&quot;kernel&quot;]" type="object" classname="App\Http\Kernel" children="1" numchildren="7"></property><property name="request" fullname="$GLOBALS[&quot;request&quot;]" type="object" classname="Illuminate\Http\Request" children="1" numchildren="37"></property><property name="GLOBALS" fullname="$GLOBALS[&quot;GLOBALS&quot;]" type="array" children="1" recursive="1"></property><property name="__composer_autoload_files" fullname="$GLOBALS[&quot;__composer_autoload_files&quot;]" type="array" children="1" numchildren="29"></property></property></response>
[14740]
```

I'm trying to debug a part of the code, I have set the breakpoint on Sublime Text, enabled the breakpoint and "Start Debugging" Option.

Comment: I do not see any "Unknown error" message in your log. if you are referring to `breakpoint_set -i 14 -t exception -x "Unknown error"` line, then it's not an error -- it's your editor setting up exception breakpoint for Unknown Error (similar to other types: Deprecated, Notice, Warning etc).

Comment: but It doesnt run the breakpoint, and it connects with the xdebug and all

Comment: So the issue is with something else. For example: 1) bad line for a breakpoint (Xdebug cannot stop at that particular line); 2) that code is not getting executed; 3) maybe missing or bad path mapping (if it's a remote debug or symlinks are involved). It can be anything but it definitely not related to "unknwon error". I do not know your project setup so cannot say that for sure (need to see screensohts etc). But try placing `xdebug_break();` in your code and see if it will stop there.